# Model Plugin with QT objects, is it possible?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can QT objects (e.g. A QMainWindow) be declared within a ModelPlugin, and if so can an example be provided? I want to create a plugin to control a model joints so when the model is inserted in gazebo a new window with personalized controls is displayed.

In the header file along from the class that inherits from ModelPlugin i tried declaring another class that inherits from QMainWindow, it compiles just fine but when the plugin is included in a sdf model and i insert it to gazebo it fails to load the plugin with an undefined symbol error for the class inheriting from QMainWindow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8252/model-plugin-with-qt-objects,-is-it-possible?/) by [PML](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1147/pml/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am not sure if you can do it from a Model Plugin, if you manage let me know ;)

However, you can access the QT parts via the [GUI overlay](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gui_overlay&cat=user_input).

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-03-16**:
You can't use QT object from a model plugin. As Andrei mentioned, a  GUI overlay is the correct way to go.

**Comment by [PML](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1147/pml/) on 2015-03-16**:
Alright, thanks for the answers.

The only way to interact with a model in this case is by using the transport layer, correct?